# Provide users with YouTube videos related to some content

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

For an application we are building we would like to create a feature that provides some related videos to the content the user is viewing. I thought that would be as easy as just understanding how YouTube API work but apparently there's a very strict limitation in terms of quota.

YouTube provides 10.000 points and if I had to implement the idea with a search endpoint that would mean just 100 searches per day. One can always ask for a quota extension, but there are no rules, pricing or certainty of extension.

Is there any other way I can provide the users with some related YouTube videos? Should I be faithful in quota extension and stick to 100 searches for now?

I would like to get in touch with someone from Google to ask them if there is a chance a quota extension and how much would that be given the feature we want to build before actually building it. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: (Not sure I fully grasp your issue, but am trying to respond anyway). (1) The YouTube Data API is a free service, no pricing attached at all. (2) SO is not Google support, by no means (in spite of Google developers site claiming the contrary). Do contact Google directly: either through the company's [own issue tracker site](https://issuetracker.google.com), or, otherwise, via the [YouTube API Services - Audit and Quota Extension Form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form).

Comment: @stvar Thank you for the answer. I saw the quota extension form, but what I understand there, is that you are supposed to already have a client that uses YT API. Which isn't my case. My case is more understanding how much quota I can have and under what conditions, to see if it's worth building a feature that uses it at all. Do you think the issue tracker and the form work as well for this case?

Comment: I'll try them both; but, in my experience, the issue tracker does not record such questions as yours. Nonetheless, if you'll try, maybe you'll get some official accounts on that matter. With respect to the quota extension form, again, my experience is negative in the sense that I know no SO post recording the experience other users had posting questions directly through that form. Even in such (negative) situation, I cannot recommend anything else, since I know no other official channel that allows direct communication with Google staff in the matter of this API.